# What is the source of the property max.poll.records?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka with Spark streaming. I didn't override `max.poll.records` that has as a default value `500`. However when running my Spark job, I find in the logs :

`max.poll.records = 2147483647`

All my jobs display the same value even if they have different batch interval.

So what is the source of this value?

- Kafka server version : 0.10.0
- Kafka spark integration for application version : "org.apache.spark"
  %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % 2.1.1
- Spark application version : 2.2.0
- Spark server version : 2.1.1

I have topics of 10 repartitions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for `max.poll.records` is `2147483647` in [Kafka 0.10.0](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/documentation.html), it has been changed to `500` in [Kafka 0.10.1](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/documentation.html).

> [**Notable changes in 0.10.1.0**](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_1010_notable)
>
> (...) and the default value of max.poll.records has been changed to 500.